# Long connections with Node.js, how to reduce memory usage and prevent memory leak? Also related with V8 and webkit-devtools

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, sockets, tcp

Here is what I'm trying to do: I'm developing a Node.js http server, which will hold long connections for pushing purpose(collaborate with redis) from tens of thousands of mobile clients in a single machine.

Test environment：

```
1.80GHz*2 CPU/2GB RAM/Unbuntu12.04/Node.js 0.8.16
```

At the first time, I used "express" module, with which I could reach about 120k concurrent connections before swap being used which means the RAM is not enough. Then, I switched to native "http" module, I got the concurrency up to about 160k. But I realized that there are still too many functionality I don't need in native http module, so I switched it to native "net" module(this means I need to handle http protocol by myself, but that's ok). now, I can reach about 250k concurrent connections per single machine.

Here is the main structure of my code:

```
var net = require('net');
var redis = require('redis');

var pendingClients = {};

var redisClient = redis.createClient(26379, 'localhost');
redisClient.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    var client = pendingClients[channel];
    if (client) {
        client.res.write(message);
    }
});

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    var buffer = '';
    socket.setEncoding('utf-8');
    socket.on('data', onData);

    function onData(chunk) {
        buffer += chunk;
        // Parse request data.
        // ...

        if ('I have got all I need') {
            socket.removeListener('data', onData);

            var req = {
                clientId: 'whatever'
            };
            var res = new ServerResponse(socket);
            server.emit('request', req, res);
        }  
    }
});

server.on('request', function (req, res) {
    if (res.socket.destroyed) {            
        return;
    }

    pendingClinets[req.clientId] = {
        res: res
    };

    redisClient.subscribe(req.clientId);

    res.socket.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    res.socket.on('close', function () {
        delete pendingClients[req.clientId];

        redisClient.unsubscribe(req.clientId);
    });
});

server.listen(3000);

function ServerResponse(socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}
ServerResponse.prototype.write = function(data) {
    this.socket.write(data);
}
```

Finally, here are my questions:

1. How can I reduce the memory usage so that increase the concurrency farther?
2. I'm really confused about how to calculate the memory usage of Node.js process. I know Node.js powered by Chrome V8, there is **process.memoryUsage()** api and it return three values: rss/heapTotal/heapUsed, what's the difference between them, which part should I concern more, and what's the exactly composition of the memory used by the Node.js process?
3. I worried about memory leak even though I have done some tests and there don't seem to be a problem. Are there any points I should concern or any advises?
4. I found a doc about [V8 **hidden class**](https://developers.google.com/v8/design?hl=en#prop_access), as it described, does that mean whenever I add a property named by **clientId** to my global object **pendingClients** just like my code above, there will be a new hidden class be generated? Dose it will cause memory leak?
5. I used [webkit-devtools-agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent) to analyze heap map of the Node.js process. I started the process and took a heap snapshot, then I sent 10k requests to it and disconnected them later, after that I took a heap snapshot again. I used the **comparison** perspective to see the difference between these two snapshots. Here is what I got:
   [image]
   Could anyone explain this? The number and size of (array)/(compiled code)/(string)/Command/Array increased a lot, what does this mean?

**EDIT**:
How did I run the loading test?

1. Firstly, I modified some parameters both on server machine and client machines（to achieve more than 60k concurrency need more than one client machine, because one machine only have 60k+ ports(represented by 16 bit) at most）
   1.1. Both one the server and the client machines, I modified the file descriptor use these commands in the shell where the test program will be run in:

   ulimit -Hn 999999
   ulimit -Sn 999999
   1.2. On the server machine, I also modified some net/tcp related kernel parameters, the most important ones are:

   net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 786432 1048576 26777216
   net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 16384 33554432
   net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 33554432
   1.3. As to the client machines:

   net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
2. Secondly, I wrote a custom simulate client program using Node.js, since most load test tools, ab, siege, etc, are for short connections, but I'm using long connections and have some special requirements.
3. Then I started the server program on a single machine, and three client program on the other three separated machines.

**EDIT**:
I did reach 250k concurrent connections on a single machine(2GB RAM), but turned out, it's not very meaningful and practical. Because when a connection connected, I just let the connection pending, nothing else. When I tried to sent response to them, the concurrency number dropped down to 150k around. As I calculated, there is about 4KB more memory usage per connection, I guess it's related to **net.ipv4.tcp_wmem** which I set to **4096 16384 33554432**, but even I modified it to smaller, nothing changed. I can't figure out why.

**EDIT**:
Actually, now I'm more interested in how much memory per tcp connection uses and what's the exactly composition of the memory used by a single connection? According to my test data:

> 150k concurrency consumed about 1800M RAM(from **free -m** output), and the Node.js process had about 600M RSS

Then, I assumed this:

> - (1800M - 600M) / 150k = 8k, this is the kernel TCP stack memory usage of a single connection, it consists of two parts: read buffer(4KB) + write buffer(4KB)(Actually, this doesn't match my setting of **net.ipv4.tcp_rmem** and **net.ipv4.tcp_wmem** above, how does the system determine how much memory to use for these buffers?)

> - 600M / 150k = 4k, this is the Node.js memory usage of a single connection

Am I right? How can I reduce the memory usage in both aspects?

If there are anywhere I didn't describe well, let me know, I'll refine it!
Any explanations or advises will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: First impression is that 250k on a machine with those specs is amazing.  Might be time to focus on getting all those users you're worried about now. =P

Comment: How are you measuring the number of concurrent connections?

Comment: Side note: it is best to stick to a smaller number of specific questions when asking on a stackexchange site.  You'll get more answers that way.

Comment: @tehgeekmeister getting those users is not my concern, I'm just concern about tech factor and I really want to do the best:)

Comment: @tehgeekmeister There are some details I didn't show in the codes above: the server also has a statistic api, so I can see how many pending clients are online in a specific time.                                   I have a lot questions in my head about this high concurrency issue(questions above just part of them) and they are obviously related, so I think raising them together maybe better.

Comment: If my answer doesn't resolve your questions, then perhaps I misunderstood.  Try clarifying more, and I'll do what I can to answer it for you.

Comment: Again, how are you measuring number of concurrent connections?  I'm skeptical that you're actually reaching that many, unless you've modified the file descriptor limits I referenced in my answer.

Comment: @tehgeekmeister I had a counter in my real codes to show me how many concurrent connections there are, count the file descriptor using **lsof** or opening connections using **netstat** can tell me the concurrency, too. I did modify the file descriptor limits.

Comment: Read the new bits.  Sorry, seems you're better informed on this topic than I am, and it's outside of the scope of things I'm focusing on teaching myself at the moment, so hopefully someone else can help you out.

Comment: I know this is a long shot, but is it possible you share the source code for this somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

1. I think you shouldn't worry about further decreasing memory usage.  From that readout you included, it seems you're pretty close to the bare minimum conceivable (I interpret it as being in bytes, which is standard when a unit isn't specified).
2. This is a more in depth question than I can answer, but here's what [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size).  The heap is where dynamically allocated memory comes from in unix systems, as best I understand.  So, the heap total seems like it'd be all that is allocated on the heap for your usage, whereas the heap used is how much of what's allocated you've used.
3. Your memory usage is quite good, and it doesn't seem you actually have a leak.  I wouldn't worry yet. =]
4. Don't know.
5. This snapshot seems reasonable.  I expect some of the objects created from the surge of requests had been garbage collected, and others hadn't.  You see there's nothing over 10k objects, and most of these objects are quite small.  I call that good.

More importantly, though, I wonder how you're load testing this.  I've tried to do massive load testing like this before, and most tools simply can't manage to generate that kind of load on linux, because of the limits on the number of open file descriptors (generally around a thousand per process by default).  As well, once a socket is used, it is not immediately available for use again.  It takes some significant fraction of a minute, as I recall, to be usable again.  Between this and the fact that I've normally seen the system wide open file descriptor limit set somewhere under 100k, I'm not sure it's possible to receive that much load on an unmodified box, or to generate it on a single box.  Since you don't mention any such steps, I think you might also need to investigate your load testing, to make sure it's doing what you think.

Comment: I have updated the post about how I run the test. You mentioned that "once a socket is used, it is not immediately available for use again", there are no such issues in my scenario, sine I use long connections. And I think you're talking about ephemeral port on the client side, not "socket".

Comment: Err, I meant file descriptor.  I think.  Maybe.  Really, we're reaching the limits of how well I understand these things.

Comment: I have removed that limitation by **ulimit** command. And thank you for your help, by the way, I'm not a native English speaker, maybe there are something I didn't explained well, let me know, I'll do my best. :)

Comment: I would love to help more, but I'm honestly unsure what more can be done at this point.  As I said before, I think you'll do better by picking out one very specific question.  I've been answering a lot of questions lately, and ones like this tend to have little success, but highly specific ones almost always get satisfactory answers.  It's okay to ask more questions, if necessary, but keeping them specific is useful.

Comment: Yeah, I admitted that I have asked too much, and **high concurrency**  is really a big topic. Iguess I'm just too lazy and impatient to ask little specific questions one by one...thank you anyway!

Comment: Did you look here https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/

Comment: @Satish Yeah, I have glanced it. Its 'leak' event is not very useful in my case, because it got to be leaking while more and more long connections connecting to the server. Its 'stats' event is not very useful, too. As to its 'heap diff' functionality, I'm using webkit-devtools to do the similar thing. But the article did give me a lot useful information. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few notes:

Do you need to wrap res in an object {res: res} can you just assign it directly

```
pendingClinets[req.clientId] = res;
```

**EDIT** another ~micro optimization that might help

```
server.emit('request', req, res);
```

passes two arguments to 'request', but your request handler really only needs the response 'res'.

```
res['clientId'] = 'whatever';
server.emit('request', res);
```

while your amount of actual data remains the same, having 1 less argument in the 'request' handlers arguments list will save you a reference pointer (a few bytes). But a few bytes when you are processing hundreds of thousands of connections can add up. You'll also save the minor cpu overhead of processing the extra argument on the emit call.

Comment: Yeah, assign it directly will work for now, so I'll try it. As to 'error' event, Node.js official document says: **The 'close' event will be called directly following this event**, so I think my approach is ok. Thanks for these notes.

Comment: @Aaron Wang - I should of RTFM'd that, I edited it out and added another small optimization that might help you squeak a little more out of your server.

Comment: Assigning **res** directly to **pendingClients** object do save some memory, about 20M every 60k connections, thanks! As to your new note, why I'm doing that way is that providing the same interface with official http module, and actually I used **req** to track request info in logging but I didn't show these details in codes above for simplification. The other reason is that **req** will be garbage collected, so I'm not very worried about it.