# Possible to simulate several concurrent connections to test a nodejs app

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, localhost

I have a simple node.js /socket.io (websockets) application running @localhost. I am trying to see how many concurrent connections it can handle. Is it possible to simulate several concurrent users on localhost itself ?

This is my half baked attempt using socket.io-client:

```
function connectAndSend(){
    socket.emit('qand',{
        code :'ubuntu'
    });
} 
socket.on('connect', function () {
});
socket.on('q', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

function callConnect(){
    console.log('calling');
    connectAndSend() ;
    setTimeout(callConnect,100) ;
}

callConnect() ;
```

As I see it this only 'emits' a new message every 100 ms and is not simulating concurrent connections.

Comment: limitless i guess . open multiple tabs in browser

Answer (score 6):

In your call to `connect`, you must tell socket.io to create a new connection for each call to `connect`. For example:

```
var socket = io.connect(server, { "force new connection": true });
```

Also, if you want to raise the outbound TCP connection limit (which seems to default to 5 connections per target), do something like

```
require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000;
```

before connecting.

But note that creating and closing tcp sockets at a fast rate will make TCP connections pile up in state `TIME_WAIT` and depending on your [OS and your network settings](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicstg/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cicstg600.doc%2Fccllal0264.htm) you'll hit a limit pretty soon, meaning you'll have to wait for those old sockets to timeout before you can establish new connections.
If I recall correctly, the limit was around 16k connections (per target ip/port combo) on Windows (both Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7), and the default `TIME_WAIT` timeout in Windows is 4 minutes, so if you create more than 16k connections in 4 minutes on Windows, you'll probably hit that wall.

Answer (score 1):

Check here:

[Long connections with Node.js, how to reduce memory usage and prevent memory leak? Also related with V8 and webkit-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049109/long-connections-with-node-js-how-to-reduce-memory-usage-and-prevent-memory-lea)

and specifically - test procedure used by the author of question mentioned above

**EDIT**:

You can use following tools to check how many requests per second your server is capable of serving

1. **ab** - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html
2. **siege** - http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/

Comment: Do you mean using webkit-devtools-agent ?

Comment: webkit-devtools-agent is a profiling tool. Updated the answer with concrete examples.